# Can you still get Minecraft Story Mode disks?

Tags: minecraft-story-mode

I found a few Minecraft Story Mode disks in Amazon and eBay, and I was wondering if I could still get Minecraft Story Mode after it's gone on a disk. Will that work mcsm was one of my favorite games and now it's being discontinued. :(

Comment: The latest information about "story mode" is linked on the top of literally every single page in the Minecraft wiki right now, even though it's not even Minecraft. It's impossible to miss.

Answer (score 2):

I simply looked up "Minecraft Story Mode (Name of a store)" and the game showed up at almost every store I looked up. And if you can buy it online you should be able to buy it in store.

Answer (score 0):

It's delisted and illegal to sell now, so the only way to get it is to download a CODEX/libminecraft cracked version.

Comment: I'm afraid we don't support piracy in any form.  With that additional knowledge, would you like to update your answer?